# Incomplete beta integral

Tags: combinatorics, analysis

Let n be greater than one, and B be the beta integral, 
$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } C_j B_{\frac{1}{n}}(j+1,j+2)=\frac{1}{n}$$

Is it correct to call this an inversion formula?
What possible ideas are there to prove this apart from this obvious one involving the intgral and so on.
I'm sorry for lack of clarity, C is jth catalan number. The 1/n stands for the limit of integration, i.e. instead of zero to 1, it is zero to 1/n. For the exact Beta integral this formula doesnt hold. It is the incomplete version.

Answer (score 2):

So we are asked to find:
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{j+1}\binom{2j}{j}\int_{0}^{1/n}x^{j+1}(1-x)^{j}\,dx.\tag{1}$$
Since:
$$ \sum_{j\geq 0}\frac{1}{j+1}\binom{2j}{j}z^j = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\tag{2}$$
we just need to find:
$$ \int_{0}^{1/n} x\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x(1-x)}}{2x(1-x)}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/n}\frac{1-|1-2x|}{2(1-x)}\,dx\tag{3}$$ 
and assuming $n\geq 2$ we have:
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{j+1}\binom{2j}{j}\int_{0}^{1/n}x^{j+1}(1-x)^{j}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/n}\frac{x}{1-x}\,dx = \color{red}{\log n-\log(n-1)-\frac{1}{n}}\tag{4}$$
that is different from what you wrote in the question body.